# JQUERY + Multiple CSS Calls

Tags: jquery

I'm successfully getting the following data:

```
        var pos = $('div#spotJoinSite').offset();  
        var width = $('div#spotJoinSite').width();
        var height = $('div#spotJoinSite').height();
```

Is it possible to combine this into one line that results in an array?

something like this:

```
var array = $('div#spotJoinSite').offset().width().height();
```

And then be able to use the array as array[0] would be offset and array[2] would be height.

Is this possible or a variation on this?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that syntax isn't possible. You could improve your code, however, by only doing the selection once:

```
var joinSite = $('#spotJoinSite'),
    pos = joinSite.offset(),
    width = joinSite.width(),
    height = joinSite.height();
```

If you really wanted an array, you could get one:

```
var joinSite = $('#spotJoinSite'),
    details = [joinSite.offset(), joinSite.width(), joinSite.height()];
```